# Cannot install ubuntu in my notebook, goes into initramfs

Tags: boot

I tried reinstalling ubuntu many times. After installation, it keeps going into initramfs shell. There is no explanation, no error in the screen. I repeatedly run boot repair and the situation keeps the same.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>c</kbd> when you are in the grub boot menu, remove `quiet` from in the line which looks something like `linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=3aeda55e-0efa-4917-a78d-f3b8eb6d6113 rw  loglevel=3 quiet splash` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue. Then it may show more error messages.

Comment: Thanks, that would have been very difficult to guess. I ended up solving the problem as in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

For someone having the same problem, I managed to fix it, so I will be sharing what I did.

When reinstalling ubuntu with the Live CD, I was previously choosing the partition /dev/sda as the place to install the boot loader in the "Something Else" menu. But I had to install it in more the specific partition where ubuntu was installed, in my case /dev/sda5. This fixed the problem after reinstalling ubuntu.